# Windows 10 with two Wi-Fi cards — Disable "known network" synchronization

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

TL;DR: I have two Wi-Fi cards installed in my laptop; Windows really wants to keep the list of known networks in sync between them; I don't want it to do this, and prior versions of Windows did not do this.  How do I stop it?

Background:
So, I do a lot of IT work and sometimes I am doing oddball stuff and am in a situation where it would be handy to have my laptop connected to two different wireless networks at the same time.  To handle this, I just added a second Wi-Fi card to my mobile workstation (borrowing the empty WWAN mPCIe slot and antennas).  The second card works fine.

Windows 10 doesn't have an issue supporting two wireless cards.  When the second card is installed, a drop-down appears above the Wi-Fi network list so that you can pick which card to use when you are making a connection.

The issue that I am running into with Windows 10 is, Windows *really* wants to keep the list of network connections of both cards in sync.  Older versions of Windows would keep them separate.  If I connected to a network with "Wi-Fi card A", and even if I set it to "automatically connect" to that network in the future, "Wi-Fi card B" would never try to connect to that network (unless I explicitly asked for it to).  On Windows 10, if I make the connection on "Wi-Fi card A", then a few minutes later I will find that "Wi-Fi card B" has also connected to that network, which is behavior that I do not want.

The strange thing is, Windows 10 still has the concept of a different list of known networks for each wireless card.  In Settings → Network & Internet → Wi-Fi, it shows the two Wi-Fi adapters separately and I can pull up the separate list of "known networks" for each one.  Some background process is synchronizing the list of connections between the two cards (and it is not immediate, there is some delay in the sync).  If I go to the list of known networks for "Wi-Fi card B" and remove the one that I don't want it to connect to, then after a minute or two, "Wi-Fi card A" will disconnect from that network and it will have been removed from that card's "known network" list.

I'm trying to figure out what is synchronizing the known networks between different cards and disable that.  I suspect that this "feature" is present just so that if you connect a new wireless adapter, you won't have to re-enter credentials for networks that you had connected to with your old one, and no one thought of the implications of this happening with two Wi-Fi cards simultaneously attached because that is a rare scenario.  I thought that it might be the Microsoft Account sync (Settings → Accounts → Sync your settings), because I know that can sync Wi-Fi network information between different PCs, but that is off and I actually totally disabled it with local group policy and yet this is still happening.

Anyone have any clue where to look?

Comment: I am surprised that card-b is picking up any SSID's at all, the WWAN slots have **cellular** U.fl pigtails to one or more cellular antenna's installed behind the screen from the factory...

Comment: I'm not sure what is different about the WWAN antennas installed in my system (compared to the WLAN ones), but they seem to work fine for Wi-Fi.  I have benchmarked the LAN throughput of "card-B" and it doesn't seem any slower than the regularly installed one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Task Scheduler, under Microsoft → Windows → WlanSvc, there is a task called "CDSSync".  I am not sure what this task is supposed to do or when it is supposed to be run (both triggers and actions are shown as "custom" and cannot be examined).  However, disabling this task stopped this synchronization behavior that I was complaining about.  I've been running with the task disabled for over a week without noticing any other negative side effects, so I'm going to call it a fix.